# c# anonymous method in a if statement?

Tags: c#, if-statement

In c#, can I write something like this :

```
if (
     (
            try {
                ...
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
     ) == true
   )
{
...
}
```

without having to move all my try/catch block inside a new function

-- edit --

OK. I complete my question. (and maybe answer it a bit).
What is supposed to be in the try/catch is a kind of XmlDocument.TryLoad(stream) (like there's a int.tryParse(string)).
I'll need it only once so that's why I'd wanted to avoid making an extra func.
So my code would be something like

```
            try {
                new XmlDocument().Load(foo);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
```

I just want to know if it goes wrong. I don't care the reason (stream empty, bad encoding).

There are a lot of interesting answers but I think what's the more appropriate for me is to create a extension method for xmlDocument. It will be way cleaner (and reusable and easier to read) than trying to force an anonymous method in my statement

Comment: In the first place, I'd try to avoid using `try/catch` like this. You are catching every exception that will be thrown. Ignoring exceptions can easily make debugging nightmare.

Comment: in fact I don't care for what exact reason it catches. In the following I will exit abruptly if return value was not true

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't use that exact syntax, no. You *could* write:

```
Func<bool> func = () =>
{
    // Code in here
};

if (func())
{
    ...
}
```

... but personally I'd extract it into a separate method. It's likely to be considerably more readable - and potentially easier to test, too.

Comment: Moving to a separate method could break encapsulation. Also it separates the code, whereas an `Func<bool>` would keep the code clean. I'd personally prefer the `Func<bool>` for readability and maintainability.

Comment: @Enigmativity: How can it break encapsulation within the same class? Separating the code would be the *desire* here - so that each method was responsible for just one aspect, splitting the testing from the response. If there's enough code in the testing to make it worth taking this approach in the first case, that's probably enough code to make it worth splitting into a method, IMO.

Comment: Methods should only handle one thing, and the goal of writing clean code should compact those methods down as concisely as possible. Personally, I find Uncle Bob suggests the most legible means of writing code.

Comment: @Enigmativity so do `private` methods break encapsulation? Or do they enable encapsulation?

Comment: @JonSkeet - Code within methods are encapsulated from the remainder of the class. Promoting fragments of code to another method breaks the in-class encapsulation, but not the intra-class encapsulation that we more typically consider. I do agree with you with regard to testing. That would indeed be a reason to separate out the code, but my question here would be how far do you go with this? You could decompose code into hundreds of methods for the sake of testing. Surely that can go too far?

Comment: @user2586804 - `private` methods enable intra-class encapsulation, lambda expressions enable `in-class` encapsulation. In the same way that `friend` enables in-assembly encapsulation. It's a matter of scope.

Comment: @Enigmativity: I think we'll have to agree to disagree about the relative merits here. I have absolutely no issue with creating a private method (or several) in order to make the code in another method simpler.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Agreed. :-)

Comment: @Enigmativity "in-class" encapsulation? Got a link to anything I could read on that? as I don't get it. Encapsulation ensures class state is maintained while the class is subjected to external manipulation. I just don't know what state you are protecting with "in-class encapsulation" as all private members are visible within the class and that's the only state that needs protecting. And I would say your class is too large if you feel the need to encapsulate parts of it from itself.

Comment: @user2586804 - Closures over lambda expressions give you in-class encapsulation, enabling you to contain state within methods rather than within the class. Do a search for "closures over lambda expressions" and have a read of what you get.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I'd recommend catching exceptions like this either, but:

```
    public static bool Try(Action action)
    {
        try
        {
            action();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Example usages

```
        int x;
        int a = 0;
        int b = 1;
        if (Try(() => x = a/b))
        {

        }

        if (Try(OtherMethod))
        {

        }

        if (Try(OtherMethod(1,2)))
        {

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (((Func<bool>)(() =>
{
    // Multi-statement evaluation
    DateTime dt = DateTime.UtcNow;

    if (dt.Hour <= 12)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}))())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Early");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Late");
}
```

Comment: Jon's answer was an anonymous method.  Mine is an inline multi-statement if, which is what frenchone was asking for.

Comment: Jons answer was to use an anonymous method.  Your answer was to use an anonymous method.  Whether that anonymous method is stored in a local variable isn't really much of a difference, certainly a change any given reader can make if they *really* want.  As far as the question, it asks how to write the code without creating a new [named] method.  You both do this.

Comment: Yes, both anonymous functions. No, mine is not named but IU take your point.  However, I've

Comment: @RichardV I like your solution but it's too verbose.

Answer (score 0):

From **C# Language Specification 5.0** (8.7.1):

> The if statement selects a statement for execution based on the value
>   of a **boolean expression**.

But your code:

```
 (
 try { return true; }
 catch (Exception ex) { return false; }
 ) == true
```

Is not a `boolean expression` but a `statement`.

Comment: So my question is : 'is it possible to wrap some code (or statement) in a way that it mimicks a boolean expression (without making it a function)'